# Dart / Polygon - Using Paper tabs in a core-toolbar

Tags: dart, polymer, dartium

I'm trying to use the paper tabs inside of a core toolbar. The code for the tabs work outside of the toolbar but I want it in it at the top of the app. Is it possible to do this?

This only shows a tool bar, doesn't show the tabs

```
<core-toolbar>
<paper-tabs selected="0">
<paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
<paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
<paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
</core-toolbar>
```

But if I put

```
<core-toolbar>
<paper-tabs selected="0">
<paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
<paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
<paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
</core-toolbar>
<paper-tabs selected="0">
<paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
<paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
<paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

then it shows tabs UNDER the toolbar and still doesn't show the tabs IN the toolbar.

Here is a screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Hf9K5d9C3TNEltTmg5RWVFY2M/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set a specific width to make the tabs show up.

Add CSS like

```dart
* /deep/ paper-tabs, 
* paper-tabs /* for browsers without native shadowDOM support */
{
  width: 200px;
}
```

to your page and the tabs will show up.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. I don't know why I couldn't find that answer before.